# How to format total order amount in email template magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email-templates

I'm trying to create an email that's sent to me after
I want the total amount of the purchase to be displayed in 2 digits . How can I display like this... Display right : $ 79.90 . Current display is wrong : $ 79,9000 .

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
                         <br>
                         <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
                        <p>Thank you for your order with Designer Wholesale Eyewear</p>
                        <p>Please make full payment of : £ {{trans "%total" total=$order.getGrandTotal() }}
                         </p>
                        <p>Account Name: GNST Service Ltd</p>
                        <p>Bank Name: Natwest </p>
                        <p>Account Number: 00000000000</p>
                        <p>Sort Code: 50-21-01</p>
                        <p>As per our terms & conditions you must make a payment within 24 hours of placing the order, if payment is not received orders are automatically cancelled</p>

                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend comment}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var comment|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Image :: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2crj.png

[image: image fail]

thanks for everything

Answer (score 2):

You should use the below way to get formatted price of Order Total.

> Step 1:- Please create events.xml file under path
> PackageName/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
      <observer name="add_Custom_variable_to_Order" instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\OrderEmail" />
   </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2:- Please create file OrderEmail.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer/

```
<?php

namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $pricingHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper
    ){
        $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $order     = &$transport['order'];
        if ($order->getGrandTotal()) {
            $formattedTotal = $this->pricingHelper->currency($order->getGrandTotal(),true,false);
            $transport['ordertotal'] = $formattedTotal;
        }
    }
}
```

> Step 3:- Add below line in your email template

```
<p>Please make full payment of : {{var ordertotal}}</p>
```

Output will be like - https://prnt.sc/1qxxap2

Please use the above way to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: It works. Thank you!